# Alternative of Debezium with aws services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, oracle-cdc

I have a use case where I need to capture the data changes in Postgres DB and push the messages to SQS.
This use can easily be achieved with debezium and Kafka but is there any alternative to do the same thing with AWS services preferably SQS? Like pushing data changes in Postgres to SQS?